# Proper way to make matplotlib use an interactive backend

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to avoid this:

```py
# Agg is a non-graphical backend; won't work here.
import matplotlib
if matplotlib.get_backend() == 'agg':
    matplotlib.use('tkagg')
```

I need matplotlib to use just any of the many interactive backends, but I don't want to mandate a particular one. If I could blacklist "agg" from my script, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an [OpenSuse bug](https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136634).

Matplotlib is supposed to pick a graphical backend if DISPLAY is set. It didn't.